# Fragment initialization order in MvvmCross 5 Navigation Service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a question about the Navigation Service introduced in MvvmCross 5.

**In Version 4:**

- I navigate with `ShowViewModel<ViewModel>()` to a Fragment
- then `Init` method of the ViewModel is called
- after that the `OnCreateView` method of the Fragment is called
- There I can manipulate the view based on ViewModel data (for example add specific elements to the view).

**In Version 5:**

- I navigate with `await NavigationService.Navigate<ViewModel>()`
- the `OnCreateView` of the Fragment is called first
- after that the `Initialize` method from the ViewModel.
- This ends in no ViewModel data while creating the Fragment view.

Is this a bug or a feature of async navigation?
If that is so wanted, is there a better way to manipulate the Fragment view based on ViewModel data?

Comment: you can use the "void OnViewModelSet()" method that can be overriden in the View.

Comment: Thanks, but the `OnViewModelSet` method is unfortunately called before the `OnCreateView` and `Initialize` methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug or a feature of async navigation?

It was by design, but has since (v5.0.4) been revised, see below of flow changes.

> If that is so wanted, is there a better way to manipulate the Fragment
>   view based on ViewModel data?

Using v5.0.4+ should yield the desired behaviour you are expecting. Where the navigation service is awaited on `Initialize()` of your `ViewModel` to complete before starting the views life cycle events.

---

**MvvmCross v5.0.0 - v5.0.3**

The behaviour you are seeing was present in MvvmCross 5.0.0-5.0.3. The flow was as follows:

- `ViewModel.Ctor`
- *(Selected Navigate calls)* `Init(parameter)` *(**deprecated**, uses reflection, rather use type safe Initialize)*
- *(Selected Navigate calls)* `ViewModel.ReloadState(savedState)`
- *(Selected Navigate calls)* `ViewModel.Start()`
- `BeforeNavigate` *(NavigationService Event)*
- **`*ViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel()`** *(Triggers view life cycles)*
- **`*ViewModel.Initialize()`**
- `AfterNavigate` *(NavigationService Event)*
- `BeforeClose` *(NavigationService Event)*
- `ViewDispatcher.ChangePresentation()`
- `AfterClose` *(NavigationService Event)*

**MvvmCross v5.0.4+**

v5.0.4+ has improved the flow and changed the navigation order:

- `ViewModel.Ctor`
- `BeforeNavigate` *(NavigationService Event)*
- **`*ViewModel.Initialize()`**
- `Init(parameter)` *(**deprecated**, uses reflection, rather use type safe Initialize)*
- `ViewModel.ReloadState(savedState)`
- `ViewModel.Start()`
- **`*ViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel()`** *(Triggers view life cycles)*
- `AfterNavigate` *(NavigationService Event)*
- `BeforeClose` *(NavigationService Event)*
- `ViewDispatcher.ChangePresentation()`
- `AfterClose` *(NavigationService Event)*

---

**Additional Information**

You can check out the GitHub issue([#1968](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1968)) logged around the navigation order. Additionally, you can check out the pull request([#1971](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1971)) which updated the `Initialize` order for version 5.0.4.

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed answer! I already had installed 5.0.5. But the new order was only taken over after cleaning the solution. My fault :/

Comment: This is going to change again in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/2072 on MvvmCross 5.2.0. It is for a reason we left ShowViewModel in, so we can stabilize the NavigationService in the following releases.